# Integrate AppMetrics into a xUnit only project

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, metrics

I have a .NET Core 3 solution which consists of a xUnit test project and a .NET Standard class library. The sole purpose of this solution to run integration tests for our ecossystem.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: .NET Core solution overview]

My next goal is to integrate AppMetrics into this solution so I can collect and report some metrics to be consumed by my Prometheus setup.

Is there any way to perform a "standalone integration", that is, to produce solo metrics on each test case, or I have to create a WebAPI project into this solution so it serves as a server for my Prometheus setup to consume?

I already have a .NET Core WebAPI solution generating metrics, and after searching the AppMetrics docs I found nothing regarding standalone solutions or console applications.

Comment: Metrics will be about the implementation code and if you have already instrument the implementation, what do you expect to get from instrumenting the tests?

Comment: About adding AppMetrics to a console app, there is an example in the documentation https://www.app-metrics.io/getting-started/#configuring-a-console-application

Comment: @jjchiw thank you for the link, I must have missed it. About the metrics, I want to collect some regarding execution time for each test, the number of errors in each test and globally the number of failing test cases (just to name a few).